# Modal Gets Correct Path in controller but is not Showing up

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I have a dropdown menu with 2 choices, when you choose either of them a modal should appear with the contents of the file in order for the user to edit and save the changes.

I used break points and i know that the process passes correctly through my controller but the modal is not showing up.

Below is the dropdown menu in the cshtml of "Home"

```
<div class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 7px;">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Configuration
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item load-config" href="#" id="btn-config" data-id="config">Codecept</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item load-config" href="#" id="btn-json-config" data-id="steps-file">Step File</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When a choice is selected i call the follow jquery

```
$(".load-config").click(function () {
        var repository = $("#repositories").val();
        var connectionId = sessionStorage.getItem("connectionId");
        var branch = $("#branches").val();
        var file = $(this).data("id");
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            data: { connectionId: connectionId, repositoryName: repository, branch: branch, file: file},
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCurrentConfiguration", "Home")',
            success: function (data) {
                codeMirrorEditor.setValue(data.content);
                $("#modal-code-editor").modal('show');
                $("#modal-title").html(data.title);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    codeMirrorEditor.refresh();
                }, 200);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error: could not cancel running test...")
            }
        });
    });
```

And below you will find the cshtml for the modal

```
<div id="modal-code-editor" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content" style="height: 768px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-title"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

<script>
    var t;
    $('#btn-config,#btn-json-config').click(function () {
        button = $(this).attr('id');
    });
    $("#btn-save-code").click(function (e) {
        var connectionId =  sessionStorage.getItem("connectionId");
        var filename = $("#modal-title").html();
        var contents = codeMirrorEditor.getValue();
        var repository = $("#repositories").val();
        var branch = $("#branches").val();
        var file = button;

        var token = $("#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input").val();
        var dataWithToken = {
            __RequestVerificationToken: token,
            filename: filename,
            connectionId: connectionId,
            fileContents: contents,
            repositoryName: repository,
            branch: branch,
            file: file
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: dataWithToken,
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveFileContents", "Home")',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#modal-code-editor").modal('hide');
                $.growl.notice({ message: "File saved successfully" });
            },
            error: function () {
                $.growl.error({ message: "Saving file failed" });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to press F12 in your browser to check whether there are errors in console tab or not.It is very likely that you ajax success function has errors before showing modal.Besides, does the modal html also in the same view of dropdownlist?

Comment: thanks for the help. it seems that a major refactoring of the code changed a lot of things. i finally found what was wrong with the help of some colleagues. But the F12 solution helped me navigate to the correct solution.